# react-native-calendars Timeline component passes undefined into onEventPress

Tags: react-native, velo, react-native-calendars

Specifically in the Timeline component in `renderTimeLineListItem`, when I press on an event, an undefined value is passed into the `onEventPress` callback. However, when a Fast Refresh happens in my Simulator and I press the event again, onEventPress receives the proper event instead of an `undefined` value. I've logged the props and they remain unchanged. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
// ... imports

export const AppointmentTimeline = ({ navigation }) => {
  // One month ago
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(
    startOfMonth(subMonths(new Date(), 1)),
  )
  // One month ahead
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(endOfMonth(addMonths(new Date(), 1)))
  const { appointments } = useAppointment({ startDate, endDate })
  const [groupedAllDayEvents, setGroupedAllDayEvents] = useState([])
  const [groupedEvents, setGroupedEvents] = useState([])
  const [markedDates, setMarkedDates] = useState({})
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(getDateFormatted(new Date()))
  const [isDatePickerOpen, setIsDatePickerOpen] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <HeaderIconButton onPress={calendarIconOnPress} icon={calendarIcon} />
      ),
    })
  }, [calendarIcon, calendarIconOnPress, navigation])

  const calendarIconOnPress = useCallback(() => setIsDatePickerOpen(true), [])
  const calendarIcon = useMemo(
    () => require('app/assets/images/icons/calendar.png'),
    [],
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    if (appointments) {
      const { groupedAllDayEvents: allDay, groupedEvents: grouped } =
        getGroupedEventsByDate(appointments)
      setGroupedAllDayEvents(allDay)
      setGroupedEvents(grouped)
      const marked = getMarkedDatesFromGroupedEvents(allDay, grouped)
      setMarkedDates(marked)
    }
  }, [appointments])

  const onPressAppointment = useCallback(
    appointment => {
      navigation.navigate('ViewAppointment', {
        appointmentId: appointment.data.id,
      })
    },
    [navigation],
  )

  const onPressToday = useCallback(() => {
    clearSelectedMarkedDate()
    const todayString = getDateFormatted(new Date())
    setSelectedDate(todayString)
  }, [clearSelectedMarkedDate])

  const onDateChanged = useCallback(
    date => {
      clearSelectedMarkedDate()
      setSelectedDate(date)
    },
    [clearSelectedMarkedDate],
  )

  const clearSelectedMarkedDate = useCallback(() => {
    const markedDatesCopy = cloneDeep(markedDates)
    if (markedDatesCopy[selectedDate]) {
      markedDatesCopy[selectedDate].selected = false
    }
    setMarkedDates(markedDatesCopy)
  }, [markedDates, selectedDate])

  const onSelectDate = useCallback(
    date => {
      const { dateString } = date
      const markedDatesCopy = cloneDeep(markedDates)
      if (markedDatesCopy[dateString]) {
        markedDatesCopy[dateString].selected = true
      } else {
        markedDatesCopy[dateString] = {
          selected: true,
        }
      }
      setMarkedDates(markedDatesCopy)
      setSelectedDate(dateString)
      setIsDatePickerOpen(false)
    },
    [markedDates],
  )

  const onCancelSelectDate = useCallback(() => {
    setIsDatePickerOpen(false)
  }, [])

  const renderArrow = useCallback(
    direction => (direction === 'left' ? <ChevronLeft /> : <ChevronRight />),
    [],
  )

  const renderTimelineEvent = useCallback(e => {
    return e.height <= 50 ? (
      <ExtraSmallEventCard title={e.title} />
    ) : e.height <= 100 ? (
      <SmallEventCard event={e} />
    ) : (
      <FullEventCard
        cardWidth={e.width}
        event={e}
        numberOfLines={e.isLessThan90Minutes ? 1 : 2}
      />
    )
  }, [])

  const renderTimeLineListItem = useCallback(
    props => {
      const todayString = getDateFormatted(new Date())
      const isToday = props.date[0] === todayString
      console.log('props', props)
      return (
        <View style={styles.timelineContainer}>
          {!isToday && <TodayButton onPress={onPressToday} />}
          {groupedAllDayEvents[props.date] && (
            <AllDayEventsContainer>
              {groupedAllDayEvents[props.date].map(event => (
                <AllDayCard
                  onPress={() => onPressAppointment(event)}
                  key={event.id}
                  title={event.title}
                />
              ))}
            </AllDayEventsContainer>
          )}
          <Timeline
            events={props.events}
            date={props.date[0]}
            onEventPress={onPressAppointment}
            timeStep={60}
            theme={styles.timelineTheme}
            format24h={false}
            renderEvent={renderTimelineEvent}
            scrollToFirst={true}
            {...props}
          />
        </View>
      )
    },
    [
      groupedAllDayEvents,
      onPressAppointment,
      onPressToday,
      renderTimelineEvent,
    ],
  )

  const onMonthChange = useCallback(date => {
    const localDate = new Date(date.dateString + 'T00:00:00')
    const oneMonthAgo = subMonths(localDate, 1)
    const oneMonthAhead = addMonths(localDate, 1)
    const updatedQueryStartDate = startOfMonth(oneMonthAgo)
    const updatedQueryEndDate = endOfMonth(oneMonthAhead)
    setStartDate(updatedQueryStartDate)
    setEndDate(updatedQueryEndDate)
  }, [])

  return (
    <CalendarProvider
      onMonthChange={onMonthChange}
      date={selectedDate}
      disabledOpacity={0.6}
      onDateChanged={onDateChanged}>
      <SelectCalendarDateModal
        selectedDate={selectedDate}
        onClose={onCancelSelectDate}
        onSelectDate={onSelectDate}
        isOpen={isDatePickerOpen}
        setIsOpen={setIsDatePickerOpen}
      />
      <ExpandableCalendar
        todayButtonPosition='right'
        theme={baseCalendarTheme}
        renderArrow={renderArrow}
        initialPosition='closed'
        firstDay={1}
        markedDates={markedDates}
      />
      <TimelineList
        showNowIndicator={true}
        scrollToNow={true}
        events={groupedEvents}
        renderItem={renderTimeLineListItem}
      />
    </CalendarProvider>
  )
}
```

An example of one instance of the props in `renderTimeLineListItem`:

```
{
   "date":[
      "2023-11-04"
   ],
   "events":[
      {
         "color":"white",
         "data":[
            "Object"
         ],
         "end":"2023-11-04T16:43:00Z",
         "id":201,
         "start":"2023-11-04T15:43:00Z",
         "title":"Nov 4th"
      }
   ],
   "initialTime":"undefined",
   "key":"2023-11-04",
   "numberOfDays":1,
   "onChangeOffset":[
      "Function anonymous"
   ],
   "scrollOffset":900,
   "scrollToFirst":false,
   "scrollToNow":false,
   "showNowIndicator":false,
   "timelineLeftInset":72
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case it helps anybody, but removing the `useCallback` from the method I'm passing into `onEventPress` works.

```
  const onPressAppointment = useCallback(
    appointment => {
      navigation.navigate('ViewAppointment', {
        appointmentId: appointment.data.id,
      })
    },
    [navigation],
  )
```